# An intelligent unzipping program for windows

Tags: windows, zip

Oftentimes I'll have one of two problems when unzipping an archive in windows. Either I'll get a duplicate folder structure

`Extract to "New Folder\"`:

```
Downloads\NewApp.zip
Downloads\NewApp\
Downloads\NewApp\NewApp\
Downloads\NewApp\NewApp\File1
Downloads\NewApp\NewApp\File2
Downloads\NewApp\NewApp\...
```

Or I'll get an explosion of the app's files in the same directory where the compressed archive resides:

`Extract here`:

```
Downloads\NewApp.zip
Downloads\NewApp.exe
Downloads\NewApp.cfg
Downloads\NewApp.nfo
Downloads\NewApp.dll
...
```

I'm looking for an intelligent zip application that will determine whether the contents are in a subfolder or not, and expand it in a way that doesn't give me duplicate folder.

Comment: +1 Cross-site duplicate without a real answer: http://superuser.com/questions/699510/how-to-unzip-a-zip-file-to-a-folder-but-avoid-duplicate-folders

Comment: I've had this issue for ever on Windows, hopefully someone found a solution. The built-in archive tool on Ubuntu does it well.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Check out my answer below :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dearchiver that can "intelligently" decide whether to extract into a new folder or not](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/dearchiver-that-can-intelligently-decide-whether-to-extract-into-a-new-folder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is *exactly* [Bandizip](https://www.bandisoft.com/bandizip/) by Bandisoft.

In Bandizip's settings, select the `Context Menu` heading.  Then, under `Extraction Menu`, enable `Extract Automatically`.

If you like, you can even enable the `Extract Automatically` functionality as the default double-click action by selecting `Extract Automatically` in the `Double-click Action` section of that same settings page.

When you use Bandizip's `Extract Automatically` functionality, it will create a subfolder only when one is needed.  If the zip file only contains a single file or subfolder, it will *not* create a subfolder.  If the zip file contains a bunch of files, it will automatically create a new subfolder for you.

Enjoy!

[image]

*Image source: bandisoft.com*

Comment: Double points: here and on super user :-) Nice answer

Comment: Is it possible to install this (and use the "extract automatically on double click" feature) without installing the context menu? This looks great, but I hate adding extra context menus in Windows--it just feels "messy", imo.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I'm not sure, but I think so.  The double-click functionality and the context menu functionality are both highly customizable.