# Open source smart extract

Tags: windows, open-source, file-compression

I would like a program that:

1. If top layer of archive is just single item, then extract here
2. If top layer of archive is several items, then extract to new folder

I see these:

- http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/28104
- http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1857

but I would like an open source solution if possible.

Answer (score -3):

[7-ZIP](http://www.7-zip.org/) does this when using the Extract to.. menu option, is open source and supports a variety of archive formats.

I realize now that what you're actually asking is to ignore the intent of the root folder. An option like "Extract to this folder name" is predictable. There is a clear intent either to splurge the root into a folder vs always make sure there is a root folder. While "ignore root subfolder as long as its the only one" is not.

It is my opinion you will have a hard time finding an archiver that uses this logic.

Comment: The name of the archive is used as the folder name. It shows up in the menu as Extract to and then the name of the archive.

Comment: Where to find it (your post misses a link)? And is it open source, as requested by OP? And does it really smartly decide by itself, as requested? According to the comment on [this linked answer](/a/28106/185), it seems not.

Comment: It behaves exactly as I described. The answer you linked is about "Extract here" which explicitly means extract INTO this folder NOT make a subfolder. Therefor the expectation there is just wrong.

If you ask 7-zip to create a folder with "Extract to [archive name]" it will create a folder with that name and extract the contents into it UNLESS there archive contains a single root folder with the same name as the archive in which it will extract the contents of that inner folder.

Comment: If the archive contains a single FOLDER with the same NAME as the archive, then this solution works. but if it is a single FILE or single folder with a different NAME then his solutions fails